# Как переделать программу, чтобы запоминала предыдущее значение переменной

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Я сделал циклический парсер, который выдает по одной строке из файла в gist на гитхабе. Как можно это переделать, чтобы при вызове команды key, бот выдавал 1 ключ, а потом уже 2 и так далее?

Сейчас проблема в том, что при вводе команды key, бот выдает один и тот же ключ,а если убрать break он начинает спамить всеми строками, а мне нужно по очереди. Извините, если немного запутал

```
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

@bot.message_handler(commands=['key'])
def get_keys(m):
    global user_key
    url = 'https://gist.github.com/doNoteXecute/95d6fdb107bc1e2e8d7eefc7634c85d8'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    n = 0
    while True:
        n = n + 1
        user_key = soup.find('td', {'id': 'file-keys-LC' + str(n)}).text
        break
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, user_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую Вам использовать атрибуты функции для сохранения переменной-счётчика.

***Пример:***

```py
def job():
    print('Do something...')
    job.i += 1


job.i = 0
job()
job()
print(job.i)
```

***stdout:***

```html
Do something...
Do something...
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key_mas=[]    
elms = soup.select('td.file-test-LC1 class.blob-code.blob-code-inner.js-file-line)
for i in elms:
    key_mas.append(i.text)
bot.send_message(m.chat.id, '\n'.join(key_mas))
```

Он выведет одним сообщением все ключи

Если тебе нужно с каждым последующим сообщением, то:

```
#Всё тоже самое
for i in range(len(key_mas)):
     bot.send_message(m.chat.id, key_mas[i])
```

Если что-то не так, то подправьте, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

@bot.message_handler(commands=['key'])
def get_keys(m, n=[0]):
    global user_key
    url = 'https://gist.github.com/doNoteXecute/95d6fdb107bc1e2e8d7eefc7634c85d8'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    while True:
        n[0] += 1
        user_key = soup.find('td', {'id': 'file-keys-LC' + str(n[0])}).text
        break
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, user_key)
```

Сейчас все работает, как мне нужно. Но появилась новая проблема, теперь бот если ввести команду больше одного раза, это тоже засчитает и пропустит строку, а мне нельзя чтобы он пропускал. Нужно сделать так чтобы после первого ввода пользователя бот игнорировал его на эту команду.